# JDBC Query using connection pool

Tags: java, jdbc

I have a connection pool interface :

```
public interface ConnectionPool {
    Connection getConnection() throws SQLException;
    boolean releaseConnection(Connection connection);
}
```

I need to implement this methods. I found an example of realization of connection pool. Here is the code:

```
public class ConnectionPoolImpl implements ConnectionPool{

    private List<Connection>availableConnections = new ArrayList<Connection>();
    private List<Connection>usedConnections = new ArrayList<Connection>();
    private final int MAX_CONNECTIONS = 5;

    private String URL;
    private String USERID;
    private String PASSWORD;


    /** Initialize all 5 Connections and put them in the Pool **/
    public ConnectionPoolImpl(String Url, String UserId, String password) throws SQLException {
        this.URL = Url;
        this.USERID = UserId;
        this.PASSWORD = password;

        for (int count = 0; count <MAX_CONNECTIONS; count++) {
            availableConnections.add(this.createConnection());
        }
    }

    /** Private function,
     used by the Pool to create new connection internally **/

    private Connection createConnection() throws SQLException {
        return DriverManager
                .getConnection(this.URL, this.USERID, this.PASSWORD);
    }


    /** Public function, used by us to get connection from Pool **/
    public Connection getConnection() {
        if (availableConnections.size() == 0) {
            System.out.println("All connections are Used !!");
            return null;
        } else {
            Connection con =
                    availableConnections.remove(
                            availableConnections.size() - 1);
            usedConnections.add(con);
            return con;
        }
    }

    /** Public function, to return connection back to the Pool **/
    public boolean releaseConnection(Connection con) {
        if (null != con) {
            usedConnections.remove(con);
            availableConnections.add(con);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /** Utility function to check the number of Available Connections **/
    public int getFreeConnectionCount() {
        return availableConnections.size();
    }

}
```

Now I have a problem of using this pool in my DAO.

My DAO realization:

```
public class EmployeeImpl implements Employee {

private ConnectionPool connectionPool;

public Employee getById(Long id) {
        try (Connection connection = connectionPool.getConnection();
            PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(SELECT_QUERY))
        {
       // 
            }
    

     return employee;
}
```

I dont know how its better to connect to my pool. Better create object ConnectionPoolImpl like this in my
EmployeeImpl class:

```
ConnectionPoolImpl conn = new ConnectionPoolImpl("MyUrl", "user", "password");
```

and then `conn.getConnection` to each my query. But this realization doesn't include my interface (field). How it is better to connect to my pool? The only constraint is I need to implement my interface. Explanation will be appreciated.

Comment: I'd recommend not to try to roll your own connection pool, but instead use a library like HikariCP, Apache DBCP or c3p0. The proper way to release a connection is to call `close()` on the connection. A properly implemented connection pool will use that to return the connection to the pool, so there is no need for a `releaseConnection()` method. At first glance I already see glaring concurrency problems with your own connection pool.

Answer (score 0):

I would use like [HikariCP](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP) connection pooling library to handle database connection pool effectively and configure the number of connections than handling it as described in your questions because there are a lot of things to take care
which in my view better to use these kind of pooling library and wrap it to the implementation of `ConnectionPool`.

For the implementation I would prefer to have constructor in `EmployeeImpl` with parameter `ConnectionPool`.
I would create `ConnectionPool` instance with `ConnectionPool conn = new ConnectionPoolImpl("MyUrl", "user", "password");` and while creating `EmployeeImpl` instance I would pass the `conn` in this way my `EmployeeImpl` is tied to the interface not the implementation which gives me the flexibility of changing the `ConnectionPool` implementation and does not require any kind of update in `EmployeeImpl` if I want to create another implementation of `ConnectionPool`.

Comment: public EmployeeImpl(ConnectionPool connectionPool) throws SQLException {
        this.connectionPool = connectionPool;
    }   Do you meant like that?

Comment: Won't it be too much connection if I will create instance for each query? Can you show me your example?